How to do a for-loop within a here document?
I am trying to create a shell script that goes multiple times through a program and calculates me some physical parameters. The program is opened in the console with "./radex" and afterwards I am asked to put in some values (for example it asks me file name, output file name, Kinetic Temperature etc.) It calculates the values and lastly asks if I wanna continue calculating (input 1) or stop (input 0). I was able to make a script looking like this
#!/bin/bash
index_array=(50 60 70)
for i in ${index_array[@]}
do
./radex<<EOF
CF_all_coll.dat
Testy2.dat
200 210
$i
1
H2
100
2.73
3e12
1
0
EOF
done

which makes it possible to create multiple files, but in order to create only 1 file I need to give a "1" instead of "0" as the last input. However when I do this it doesn't work probably because it calls ./radex again, so is there a way to

Call ./radex within the loop only once
"Mark" something as input or not input within a here-doc? Because if I put ./radex<<EOF over the for-loop, the for-loop will be taken as input.
Input something in a different way


You mean like:
for i in "${index_array[@]}"; do
   cat <<EOF
CF_all_coll.dat
Testy2.dat
200 210
$i
1
H2
100
2.73
3e12
1
0
EOF
done | ./radex

It might be simpler to first generate it, view it for debugging, and then redirect.
input=$(
for i in "${index_array[@]}"; do
   cat <<EOF
CF_all_coll.dat
Testy2.dat
200 210
$i
1
H2
100
2.73
3e12
1
0
EOF
done
)
echo "$input" # Is it correct?
./radex <<<"$input"
# or echo "$input" | ./radex


Thanks a lot, that worked very nicely for me! Do you have an idea how to get the script to always put in a "1" at the end but on the last iteration a "0"? Because "1" means it continues calculating which it should but I want it to stop after the last calculation

soo like if [[ "$i" == "${index_array[-1]}" ]]; then echo 0; else echo 1; fi? You can also do a for i in ${!index_array[@]}

UPDATE: in reply to OP's comment about writing something different in the last iteration of the for loop (which might be worth a new question).
It's possible to loop over a bash array by index, so you could check for the last element by comparing its index; or you could generate an other array with the values that you want to output at the end of each iteration. There's also other possibilities but here I chose to illustrate the second one:
#!/bin/bash

index_array=(50 60 70)

# create an array filled with "1" of the same size as "index_array"
#   and replace the last element with "0"
footer_array=( "${index_array[@]/*/1}" )
footer_array[-1]=0

for i in "${!index_array[@]}"
do
    # NOTE: putting radex's parameters in an array is just for convenience
    radex_params=(
        CF_all_coll.dat
        CF_all_coll.dat
        Testy2.dat
        200
        210
        "${index_array[i]}"
        1
        H2
        100
        2.73
        3e12
        1
        0
        "${footer_array[i]}"
    )
    # output each parameter, one per line
    printf '%s\n' "${radex_params[@]}"
done |
./radex


Thanks a lot, your approach is working as well! Im still quite new to shell scripting so I wasn't sure whether a heredoc is suitable or not. Similar to the question above do you have an idea on how to to make the script always put in a "1" except for the last loop where it should be a "0"? "1" makes the script keep calculating and "0" stops it.

There's a few ways to do that, but you'll have to be clearer on where in the output you want to put these digits

So the program looks like this, it starts via ./radex and then asks me for about 10 input parameters (mostly file names, pyhsical parameters etc.) The last input that I provide is either a "0" if I dont wanna continue the calculation or a "1" if I want to continue the calculation. I always wanna give a "1" to keep calculating except for the last loop (so basically when its finished afterwards) it should get a "0".

Hm. Do you remember offhand which bash version introduced the behavior you're exercising here with respect to arr[-1]? It's not available in 3.2, so this wouldn't work out-of-the-box on MacOS, f/e.

@CharlesDuffy I think it's been introduced in bash 4.3; I thought of replacing it with footer_array[${#footer_array[@]}-1]=0 but I let it that way because it conveys the intention in simpler terms
